# Vue router won't maintain subdirectory url (or relative path) structure when navigating routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-router

Basically I want to deploy my `dist` folder (created from Vue CLI `build`) in to any folder I like and not worry about having to set the root or base name every time I decide to move my app. Currently I have it working to the point where I can visit the URL where I've deployed the contents of the `dist` folder and all is well. However, when I navigate to the app root/base (i.e `/`) it strips the entire current directory from the URL bar and just leaves the root domain.

EXAMPLE:

**1)** I can visit `www.mywebsite.com/some-directory/other-directory/my-app`
this all works fine and I can see my app with no errors.

**2)** However, when I then click a link (which are vue router based in history mode), the URL changes to `www.mywebsite.com/the-link`.

**3)** Everything still works as expected but I want to maintain the URL to be:
`www.mywebsite.com/some-directory/other-directory/my-app/the-link`

The only way I can get the desired result is to remove `history` mode from the vue router, but this then uses those ugly hash `#` symbols in the URL which I really don't want.

**Side note:** I have also set `baseUrl: './'` in `vue.config.js` otherwise my assets fail to load.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would probably just add `some-directory/other-directory/` to the `path` of your various routes.

Comment: Thanks @SimonHyll - I've had to resort to setting `baseUrl: '/my/path/'` in `vue.config.js` for now. But I'm still interested if anyone knows a true solution. Thanks

Comment: I think the two "intended" ways for this is to either use baseUrl or to edit .htaccess, neither of which seem to be what you want

Comment: I also forgot to mention that I had to set `base: '/my/path/'` in the vue router config as well, along with `mode: 'history'`